# WHERE clause and grouped inequality using AND logical operator

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Maybe this looks pretty basic but i cannot explain the following behavior in Snowflake.

I got the following table containing 2 rows.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE foo (id integer, field1 string, field2 string);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES
  (23493132, 'Stop', 'Unexpected Downtime'),
  (23493132, 'Stop', 'Break')
;
```

Which give me the following table content

| ID | FIELD1 | FIELD2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23493132 | Stop | Unexpected Downtime |
| 23493132 | Stop | Break |

I want to select the row which got id **23493132** and where a field1 **Stop** is not associated with a field2 **Break**

I'm expecting a one-row result, the first one.

So i wrote the following query

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM foo
WHERE (id = 23493132)
    AND (field1 != 'Stop' AND field2 != 'Break')
;
```

Nothing returned

| ID | FIELD1 | FIELD2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |

On the other hand the following query using **NOT** and **equality** is giving me the expected result

```
SELECT
*
FROM foo
WHERE id = 23493132
    AND NOT (field1 = 'Stop' AND field2 = 'Break')
;
```

| ID | FIELD1 | FIELD2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23493132 | Stop | Unexpected Downtime |

Can someone explain to me what is wrong with my first query as i'm a bit confused ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> On the other hand the following query using NOT and equality is giving me the expected result
>
> AND NOT (field1 = 'Stop' AND field2 = 'Break')

The equivalent query(*):

```
SELECT    * 
FROM foo
WHERE (id = 23493132)
    AND (field1 != 'Stop' OR field2 != 'Break');
```

(*) Assuming that field1/field2 are not nullable.

---

[De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

> the negation of a conjunction is the disjunction of the negations

```
NOT (A AND B) <=> (NOT A) OR (NOT B)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on what @lukasz said:

What you seem to want to do is have the opposite of the following clause:

```
(field1 = 'Stop' AND field2 != 'Break')
```

the opposite of a clause (A and B) is actually (!A or !B)

This is because and narrows things downwards whereas or expands things outwards. So what you want is:

```
(field1 != 'Stop' OR field2 != 'Break')
```

Answer (score 0):

The first query has three conditions joined with ANDs (parenthesis don't matter here).

So it is looking for rows, which meet all three conditions.

Including `field1 != 'Stop'` - which is not met by any row.